# Resources for the Chinese section of the Gaokao?

Tags: writing, learning, culture, mainland-china, academic

The entrance examination for universities in mainland China includes a Chinese section. I'm looking for three things about this.

1) A source for questions that have been asked in previous years. For my purposes, the older the questions the better.

2) An official source describing the structure of the exam, including number and types of questions, and scoring methodologies, (machine scoring, hand scoring, who does scoring, under what conditions). I'm especially interested in guidelines for scoring composition questions.

3) results on the Chinese section, including scoring percentiles, and minimum for acceptance at various schools; especially interested in seeing these broken down by province.

Hope this doesn't get shot down as overly broad! Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: googled：＂高考试题＂ （gaokao examination questions）？

Comment: Yes, but there are a gazillion websites, most of them commercial, not official, and all with densely packed pages plastered with ads. Would still appreciate guidance from people who know their way around the labyrinth.

Comment: Every province have different standard and there are no very official information about this on the Internet by now. Maybe you can search for a series of guide books called 五年高考·三年模拟 to study this.

Comment: Ah, I see you're right. There are different versions of the exam for different provinces.  Wow, that's much more complex for me.  How can they do that if its a national entrance exam??

Answer (score 2):

2015年高考真题：http://wenku.baidu.com/topic/2015gaokao_zhenti 不过需要下载分。
2015年高考真题、答案和其它资源：http://www.eol.cn/html/g/gkst/ 可以直接下载，但是需要在论坛里多找找。
历年高考作文：http://www.gaokao.com/guangdong/gdgkzw/
另外，请善用百度站内的搜索（百度文库禁止GoogleBot访问）：http://wenku.baidu.com/search?word=2015%B8%DF%BF%BC+%CA%FD%D1%A7+%BA%FE%B1%B1

附部分题目：
**2015 Essay Prompt Guangdong: 2015年广东卷作文题**

> 阅读下面的文字，根据要求作文。
>
> 看天光云影，能测阴晴雨雪，但难逾目力所及；打开电视，可知全球天气，缺少了静观云卷云舒的乐趣。
>
> 漫步林间，常看草长莺飞、枝叶枯荣，但未必能细说花鸟之名、树木之性；轻点鼠标，可知生物的纲目属种、迁徙演化，却无法嗅到花果清香、丛林气息。
>
> 从不同的途径去感知自然，自然似乎很“近”，又似乎很“远”。
>
> 要求：1，自选角度，确定立意，自拟标题，文体不限
>
> 2，不要脱离材料内容及含义的范围
>
> 3，不少于800字
>
> 4，不得套作，不得抄袭

**2014 Essay Prompt Guangdong: 2014年广东卷作文题**

> 阅读下面的文字，根据要求作文。
>
> 黑白胶片的时代，照片很少，只记录下人生的几个瞬间，在家人一次次的翻看中，它能唤起许多永不褪色的记忆。但照片渐渐泛黄，日益模糊。
>
> 数码科技的时代，照片很多，记录着日常生活的点点滴滴，可以随时上传到网络与人分享。它从不泛黄，永不模糊，但在快速浏览与频繁更新中，值得珍惜的“点滴”也可能被稀释。
>
> 要求：
>
> 1、自选角度，确定立意，自拟标题，文体不限。
>
> 2、不要脱离材料内容及含义的范围。
>
> 3、不少于800字。
>
> 4、不得套作，不得抄袭。

**2015 Math Hubei 2015年湖北数学卷 出自[《九章算术·卷第五　商功》](https://zh.wikisource.org/zh-hans/%E4%B9%9D%E7%AB%A0%E7%AE%97%E8%A1%93#.E5.8D.B7.E7.AC.AC.E4.BA.94.E3.80.80.E5.95.86.E5.8A.9F)第（一五）题**

> 今有阳马，广五尺，袤七尺，高八尺。问︰积几何？

Discussion: http://www.guokr.com/question/605347/

Comment: Excellent.  But what is http://www.eol.cn ? do you know anything about this site?  How about http://www.gaokao.com/ ? If they are not official sites, I'm concerned about how reliable they might be.

Comment: Gaokao Exam questions are mostly released by test takers, so sometimes it is very hard to find the first-hand/official version, but in most cases its reliability is not a problem. You can find difference sources of the same exam paper. They are consistent. 

Test questions taken from official sources can be found in 《五年高考三年模拟》

Answer (score 1):

1) As @biubiubiu mentioned, the 五年高考·三年模拟 series (in the student community known as “五·三”) is an excellent and authoritative source for past gaokao exams. I don't think there are official resources including complete gaokao exams, and the typical source for students in China are non-official publications like 五·三.

2) The structure and guidelines can be found in the 高考考试说明 published annually by every provincial education bureau. They vary from province to province, but are similar to a large extent. To my knowledge these publications are usually distributed to gaokao test-takers every year and not often found in commercial bookstores.

3) When I was in high school in Beijing, I vaguely remember being given a book containing the gaokao and admission results from the previous year, in the year I was preparing for gaokao. Many local Beijing newspapers have extensive reports on such information in the weeks following gaokao as well.